# How do I compare a picture to a shape template?

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, shapes, template-matching

I am creating an app that compares the shape of an object to a bunch of template images.

For Example:

The user takes a picture of a bottle and the app will find the shape and compare it to find the type of bottle it is based on template images.

I have looked at OpenCV but I am not sure how to implement it in iOS (Xcode)

What would you recommend to do this?

Comment: Try to use Vuforia SDK https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/image-targets

Comment: This problem isnt solved yet. Depending on quality and accuracy there exist approaches from simple (chamfer matching) to complex (training a HoG detector for each object)